# Why doesn't my code script execute this CSS class?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm wondering why this image pop up class called "grow" doesn't execute even though it's mentioned in the echo script.

Here's the PHP code:

```
echo "<a href='$file'><img class='grow' src='$file' alt='$filename'></a><br>";
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
.grow img {
    transition:transform 0.25s ease;
}

.grow img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

It worked before I tried putting it into a CSS class. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `.grow img` to `img.grow`, I tend to find that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Class name 'grow' already refers to the image. So there is no need for:**

```
.grow img {
     transition:transform 0.25s ease;
}

.grow img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

**Use this css instead**

```
.grow {
     transition:transform 0.25s ease;
}

.grow:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the selectors you have used in your CSS. It is currently looking for an element with the `.grow` class and then searching for an image child within that element. For example, if you gave the anchor `<a>` the class `grow` - your CSS would work.

The following code is the correct selection for your PHP code:

```
img.grow {
    transition:transform 0.25s ease;
}

img.grow:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Explanation of why this works: the selector is searching an `<img>` with the class `grow`.